# How to convert numeric attributes to binary in weka using java?

Tags: java, weka

I'd like to convert my numeric attributes to binary in order to use attribute selection.

and for using J48 tree, numeric types are not allowed.

so I want to convert the type of the attributes.

How can I do this in java?

Thank you in advance, :)

Comment: You mean `int`, `float`, `double` aren't allowed? Use it's object wrappers `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use weka framework NumericToBinary class for this.

[NumericToBinary class](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericToBinary.html)